# R data.table, How to add 1 to each cell value is not equal to 0

Tags: r

I have binary R data.frame, the 1st column is ID. How do I add 1 to these non-zero values?

```
id      A   B  C
001     0   1  0
002     0   0  1
```

Should become

```
id      A   B  C
001     0   2  0
002     0   0  2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can multiply by the number wanted which makes use of the `0` multipled by any value returns 0

```
df1[-1] <- df1[-1] * 2
```

---

Or an option is to create a logical matrix on the subset of columns, use that to subset the values and assign the number

```
df1[-1][df1[-1] ==1] <- 2
```

Or add

```
df1[-1][df1[-1] ==1] <- df1[-1][df1[-1] ==1] + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you can treat the zeros as the mask, you are able to play some tricks like below

```
df[-1] <- df[-1]*(df[-1]+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

While I suspect the other answers will suffice, you mentioned `data.table` in the question title, so here's one specific to that package:

```r
library(data.table)
DT <- fread(header = TRUE, text = "
id      A   B  C
001     0   1  0
002     0   0  1", colClasses = list(character="id"))

sdcols <- c("A", "B", "C")
DT[, (sdcols) := .SD + (.SD != 0), .SDcols = sdcols]
DT
#     id A B C
# 1: 001 0 2 0
# 2: 002 0 0 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a binary data you can add the data with itself so `0 + 0` remains `0` and `1 + 1` will become 2. Ignoring the first `id` column of course.

```
df[-1] <- df[-1] + df[-1]
df
#   id A B C
#1 001 0 2 0
#2 002 0 0 2
```